# expected type 'i32', found 'usize'

Tags: arrays, casting, zig

I'm currently trying to solve some leetcode problems in Zig, and I'm doing the two sum problem. Here's what the entirety of my code looks like:

```
const std = @import("std");
const allocator = std.heap.page_allocator;

fn two_sum(nums: []i32, target: i32) []i32{
    var map = std.AutoArrayHashMap(i32, i32).init(allocator);
    defer map.deinit();
    var res = [2]i32{-1, -1};
    for (nums, 0..) |n, i| { // n is the number; i is the index
        if (map.get(target - n)) |v| {
            res[0] = v;
            res[1] = @as(i32, i);
            return &res;
        }
        try map.put(n, @as(i32, i));
    }
    return &res;
}

pub fn main() !void {
    var arr = [_]i32{1, 5, 8, 9, 6};
    var x = two_sum(&arr, 9);
    for (x) |n| {
        std.debug.print("{d}", .{n});
    }
}
```

However, when I run the code, I get this error:

```
error: expected type 'i32', found 'usize'
            res[1] = @as(i32, i);
                ^
```

Why is zig interpreting 1 as a `usize` and not an `i32`? And what can be done to fix this?

I tried using an explicit type cast:
res[@as(i32, 1)] = @as(i32, i);

However, that didn't work either.

Comment: i can't reproduce this with latest zig (master)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The immediate problem is that `i` has type `usize`, and you can't cast from `usize` to `i32` using `@as` since an `i32` can't hold all of the values that a `usize` might hold. Instead, use [`@intCast`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/0.10.1/#intCast) which is specifically for these situations when you know that the cast is safe. There are two such casts using `@as` that need to be changed to `@intCast`.

The `two_sum` function needs to return an error union since it is using `try` around the call to `map.put`. And since `two_sum` needs to return an error union, calls to `two_sum` need to handle that, e.g., by using `try`.

Finally, `res` is a local variable, and you shouldn't return a pointer to a local variable; the storage associated with local variables is not valid after control leaves the local scope, and attempting to access such invalid memory leads to [undefined behavior](https://ziglang.org/documentation/0.10.1/#Lifetime-and-Ownership). Instead of returning a pointer, just return (a copy of) the array.

Here is a version of OP posted code with the above changes.

```
const std = @import("std");
const allocator = std.heap.page_allocator;

fn two_sum(nums: []i32, target: i32) ![2]i32 {  // return error union
    var map = std.AutoArrayHashMap(i32, i32).init(allocator);
    defer map.deinit();
    var res = [2]i32{ -1, -1 };
    for (nums, 0..) |n, i| {
        if (map.get(target - n)) |v| {
            res[0] = v;
            res[1] = @intCast(i32, i);     // use `@intCast` instead of `@as`
            return res;                    // just return the array
        }
        try map.put(n, @intCast(i32, i));  // use `@intCast` instead of `@as`
    }
    return res;                            // just return the array
}

pub fn main() !void {
    var arr = [_]i32{1, 5, 8, 9, 6};
    var x = try two_sum(&arr, 9);  // `two_sum` returns an error union
    for (x) |n| {
        std.debug.print("{d}", .{n});
    }
    std.debug.print("\n", .{});
}
```